# netty: Can I remove unneeded features?

Tags: java, networking, netty

I need to implement a protocol on top of tcp/ip. The 3.5.3 netty jar is 1.1MB. I'd like it to be even smaller.

Netty includes features I don't need such as HTTP Tunnel, In-VM Pipe, HTTP, WebSocket, SSL, StartTLS, Google ProtBuf, zlib/gzip compression, large file transfer, RTSP.

Can I get rid of these to make the netty jar smaller? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can

- download the source
- delete the classes/methods you don't want.
- check all the tests you need still pass
- build a new jar.

You have to do this every time you upgrade the version of netty.

Given 1.1 MB costs next to nothing on disk, I doubt it is worth the effort. 1.1 MB costs 0.005 cents of HDD disk space on a and 0.09 cents on an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proguard tool:

- http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

I think it could be possible to shrink the jar to rhe features you use but you will need to configure it correctly.

But if you succeed approach should be cleaner than modifying the original jar.